# X.PagedList.Mvc.Core - Customizing Pagination with Bootstrap

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

I am trying to make pagination in **[*ASP.Net Core 3.1*](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1)** App using [***X.PagedList.Mvc.Core***](https://www.nuget.org/packages/X.PagedList.Mvc.Core/8.0.7). I am using [***Bootstrap 4.4.1***](https://getbootstrap.com/) in view as support for viewing pagination.

What I have done is-

My **Controller** is like this-

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet("Movies/{pageNo?}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int? pageNo = 1)
{
    var data = await _context.Movies.ToListAsync();
    ViewBag.onePageOfMovies = data.ToPagedList((int)pageNo, 5); // will only contain 5 data max because of the pageSize
    return View();
}
```

The **view** is like this-

```
.....
.....
@Html.PagedListPager(
    (IPagedList)ViewBag.onePageOfMovies,
    pageNo => Url.Action("Index", new { pageNo }),
    new PagedListRenderOptionsBase{
        PageClasses = new string[] { "page-link" },
        UlElementClasses = new string[] { "pagination" },
        LiElementClasses = new string[] { "page-item" },
        DisplayItemSliceAndTotal = true,
        DisplayEllipsesWhenNotShowingAllPageNumbers = true,
        DisplayLinkToFirstPage = PagedListDisplayMode.IfNeeded,
        DisplayLinkToLastPage = PagedListDisplayMode.IfNeeded
    }
)
.....
.....
```

What I am getting is like this-

[image: Real View]

But I like to have is like this-

[image: Target]

Can anyone please help how I can customize my pagination in [ASP.Net Core 3.1](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1) application?

### Re-

According to [this](https://github.com/dncuug/X.PagedList/issues/127) GitHub issue, the problem is fixed. But I am not finding it fixed in the current latest version (my used version no **8.0.7**).

Comment: In fact, the case on github is not the same as your needs.
However, he provides an idea to change the corresponding style through jquery, I think it is a good idea. I suggest that you can use F12 to change the style of the module you need to change.

Comment: Changing data with jQuery is not easy as it uses `li` element and I need to extract a `li` element and pest that to another place. The way is implementable, but I prefer a solution in the razor view, not from front end.

Answer (score 0):

The desired effect can be achieved with css.

```
.pagination-container {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

.pagination {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  gap: .625rem;
}

.page-item, .page-link {
  height: 2rem;
  width: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.PagedList-pageCountAndLocation {
  justify-content: start;
  order: -1;
  flex: 1; // expands the div to max available width
}
```

Make the container a flex row and then use the order property to manipulate the order of the content.

[Additional information about ordering flex items.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items).